# Setting <img> src to Base64-encoded image with Javascript is failing

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm trying to set `<img>` `src` with JavaScript, but the image is missing visually; it is empty. The image URL after running this code starts with `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/%27"` (I don't even know where this came from) instead of `"data: image/png"`. The variable `mySrc` is set to a Base64-encoded image.

```js
document.getElementById(id).src="'"+mySrc+"'";
```

This is what the URL looks like after setting it:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/%27data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RMNRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAQAAABAwABAAAAuAsAAAEBAwABAAAA9gkAAAIBAwADAAAAzgAAAAMBAwABAAAAAQAAAAYBAwABAAAAAgAAAA4BAgAfAAAA1AAAABIBAwABAAAAAAAAABUBAwABAAAAAwAAABoBBQABAAAA9AAAABsBBQABAAAA/AAAABwBAwABAAAAAQAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgALAAAABAEAADIBAgAUAAAAEAEAADsBAgAEAAAAUm9uAGmHBAABAAAAJAEAAHwBAAAIAAgACABJbWFnZSBjb252ZXJ0ZWQgdXNpbmcgaWZmdG9hbnkAAMDGLQAQJwAAwMYtABAnAABQaWNhc2EgMy4wAAAyMDA4OjA2OjA2IDEwOjM2OjEyAAQAAaADAAEAAAD...
```

Comment: No way of knowing without seeing more code, such as how `mySrc` is defined and populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `src` without apostrophes:

```js
document.getElementById(id).src=mySrc;
```

Comment: But there is no host text at all; I checked :(

Comment: what exactly contain `mySrc`? Where is the declaration ?

Comment: It is an image which I converted to base64 and placed the base64 into mySrc var; It is showing fine but if I set src with JS, as I show it in my question, the image info starts with http://127.0.0.1:8080/%27 and that makes my image "invisible" :( So I think where the http://127.0.0.1:8080/%27 comes from because it doesn't allow to show image right?

Comment: Thank to your notice I took off apostrophe(s) and all worked fine :)